# Intersection and union of complete subsets of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does anyone know the two following proofs?

(i) the intersection of any collection of complete subsets of metric space $(X, d)$ is complete.

and

(ii) the union of a finite number of complete subsets of metric space $(X,d)$ is complete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are not hard to prove.  What have you tried?

Comment: **Hint**, See: M. Searcóid, [Metric spaces](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aP37I4QWFRcC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=intersection+of+complete+subsets+is+complete&source=bl&ots=wDPqvKdDA3&sig=JgDNJVwCc2Ykqm7X7cmpQCyfVMk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=smtYUfCvM4LyiAf0goGgCg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=intersection%20of%20complete%20subsets%20is%20complete&f=false), p169, Theorem 10.4.1 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. If $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$, then it is a Cauchy sequence in each $A_i$.
2. If $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A_i \cup \cdots \cup A_k$ then there is an $i \leq k$ such that some subsequence of $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is contained in $A_i$.  (And a Cauchy sequence converges iff some subsequence converges.)